# Ubuntu server pre-installation can't see logical drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have a problem with my HP ProLiant DL380 G5. I need to install linux on the server but I can't seem to get past the installation disk page. I have 6 physical drives and have 5 of them in a logical drive configuration with a RAID 5 (I am not really good with RAID and logical drive setup so I am not sure what the terms are). Ubuntu server can't seem to find any drives on the system except for maybe the USB drive I have Ubuntu server on. Another thing that I noticed is that a very large error comes up when it first boots with the USB drive. I have seen on HPE that it is nothing to worry about since this specific machine does not support something in the error (Here is the link to the thread: [HPE Thread](https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/BIOS-HAS-CORRUPT-hw-PMU-RESOURCES/m-p/6011415/highlight/true#M135556)) I hope this is enough information to get an answer.

Comment: Does Ubuntu require a storage driver to see the RAID controller's drives?

Comment: Can you access a command-line terminal in the installer, and check if you 1) have either ["hpsa"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/hpsa.4.html) or ["cciss"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/cciss.4.html) in the output of `lsmod`; 2) have devices in the `/dev/cciss/` directory; 3) see any of your logical drives in the output of `lsblk` & `lsblk -f`? It might be that you're booting an old Ubuntu version that doesn't have the new hpsa driver yet, and doesn't understand the unusual device naming that the old cciss driver does.

Comment: I will have to see what the output of those are. I am also not sure how to gain commands-line access on the installing page. I also will be away for about a week so I can't check immediately seeing as it doesn't have any remote access setup besides iLO and I haven't attached the ethernet cable to that port.